# Getting location and fire a location based request with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm not really understanding how redux-saga can help me managing side effects and need a bit of explanation.

Here is my case:
I'm building a react-native app that has to fire a location based API request when the first screen is reached, display a loading while fetching and display results when got them.

**By now I got 2 reducers**: device and restaurants

`DeviceRedux.js` stores the state of the location like this:

```
{
  locationPermission: 'authorized', // one of 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted' or 'undetermined'
  locationActive: true, // if locations services are turned on or not
  locationError: '',
  lastLocation: {
    lat: 12.3456,
    lng: 65.4321,
    date: '2019-22-01T12:30:00.000+01:00,
  },
  fetchingLocation: false,
}
```

`RestaurantsRedux.js` stores the state of the restaurants like this:

```
{
  restaurantsList: [{
    name: 'Pizza for You',
    id: '123-oer-432',
  }, ...]
  fetchingRestaurants: false,
}
```

**And 2 sagas**:
`DeviceSagas.js` handles sagas about location

```
export function* getCurrentLocationSaga(action) {
  // check locations
  const locationPermission = yield call(checkLocationPermission);
  // save locationPermission in redux state
  yield put(DeviceRedux.setLocationPermission(locationPermission));

  switch (locationPermission) {
    case 'authorized'
    // 1 check if location service is enabled 
    // 2 if enabled retrieve location and save it to redux store

    // handle all other possibilities
  }
}


async function checkLocationPermission() {
  try {
    const response = await Permissions.check('location');
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR while checking location permission', error);
    return 'denied';
  }
}
```

`RestaurantsSagas.js` handles sagas about restaurants

```
export function* getRestaurantsByPosition(api, action) {
  const {
    position, 
  } = action;

  const response = yield call(api.getRestaurantsByPostion, position);

  if (response.ok) {
    yield put(RestaurantsActions.restaurantsByPositionSuccess(response.data));
  } else {
    yield handleError(response)
  }
}
```

I would like to make a new saga that starts the `getCurrentLocationSaga` and waits it to be completed with the new location, when got the new location then start a new restaurant search. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `take` [to pull future actions](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/FutureActions.html):

```
function* watchFetchLocationsAndRestourants(action) {
  yield call(getCurrentLocationSaga, action);

  // wait for: 2 if enabled retrieve location and save it to redux store
  const foundLocationsAction = yield take('SAVE_LOCATIONS_TO_REDUX');
  const restaurants = yield call(getRestaurantsByPosition, api, {payload: foundLocationsAction.locations, type: 'YOUR_TYPE'});
}
```

So you start getting current location, and saga continue executing only when `SAVE_LOCATIONS_TO_REDUX` dispatched. Next you call restaurants search using locations you've got.